# Get a return value of a function in another function which is an event

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm confused in accessing a value from a function(event) in an another function(event).My code is something like this.

```
def OnSelect(self,e):
    i=GetString()
    return i
```

and i have an another event function,

```
def OnStart(self,e):
    "this function outputs based on return value from function OnSelect()"
```

Based on the events selected on OnSelect(),The function OnStart() processes it's output.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as these are instance methods, you could assign the value to an instance attribute:

```
def OnSelect(self,e):
    self.selectedString = GetString()

def OnStart(self,e):
    self.selectedString...
    ...
```

This way in `OnStart` you're only just accessing the last value `self.selectedString` was assigned.

Of course, if you somehow need to refresh `self.selectedString` (I can't know if it makes sense in this context, so bear this in mind), just call `OnSelect` from `OnStart` to get an updated value before proceeding.